# Release build failed flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting the following when trying to build release apk
This is the following errors

Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

  ```
      flutter build apk --release
  You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
  If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
      To generate an app bundle, run:
          flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
          Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
      To split the APKs per ABI, run:
          flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
          Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.
  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
     > Android resource linking failed
       C:\Users\msubrata\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

       C:\Users\msubrata\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       7.7s
  The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
  Building plugin android_intent...
  Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
  Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    1.2s


  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_intent'.
  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 1s


  The plugin android_intent could not be built due to the issue above.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems compatibility issue for shared_preferences due to AndroidX incompatibility

You can solve this issue by migrating project to android x

Just perform following steps

Open the Flutter project (Android Folder) into Android Studio

1. Click on Refactor
2. Click on Migrate to AndroidX
3. Wait for process then click on DoRefactor (will appear at the bottom toolbar of Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading shared_preferences version